# Interpolation of variables in Jinja2 macros?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm unclear on how to pass variables as variables to a Jinja2 template macro.

I'm writing a Flask app, with the usual setup, and have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="form-row form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-2">{{form.author.label}}{% if form.author.flags.required %}*{% endif %}</div> 
  <div class="col-auto">{{form.author(class="form-control",size=40)}}</div>
</div>

<div class="form-row form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-2">{{form.title.label}}{% if form.title.flags.required %}*{% endif %}</div> 
  <div class="col-auto">{{form.title(class="form-control",size=60)}}</div>
</div>
```

[etc., a dozen times]

I wanted to write a macro to handle this, so I tried:

```
{% macro displayformline(field, size) %}
  <div class="form-row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2 label">{{ form.field.label }}{% if form.field.flags.required %}*{% endif %}</div> 
    <div class="col-auto">{{ form.field(class="form-control",size=size) }}</div>
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

to call it like:

```
{{ displayformline(author, 40) }}
```

However, this throws the error `'app.forms.BookAddForm object' has no attribute 'field'` on the `form.field.label` line. Obviously, I want the "field" in that line to be the variable "field", holding the value "author" in this example, not the text 'field' itself. (I imagine I'll have a similar issue at the "size=size" line.) How am I meant to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ...

```
{% macro displayformline(field, size) %}
  <div class="form-row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2 label">{{ field.label }}{% if field.flags.required %}*{% endif %}</div> 
    <div class="col-auto">{{ field(class="form-control",size=size) }}</div>
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

and ...

```
{{ displayformline(form.author, 40) }}
```